# How to save the choices in the save() in the model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to be able to save and retrieve the Choices , but depending on a certain value in the fields.

For example, this is my model :

```
class Business(TimeStampedModel):
        business_id = models.CharField(
            'Business ID', max_length=64, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
         legal_form = models.CharField(
        _('Legal form'), max_length=16, choices=LEGAL_CHOICES, blank=True)
         accordance = models.CharField(
            'accordance', max_length=16, blank=True)

        def save():
           radio_buttons = RADIO_BUTTON_SELECTIONS
           values = radio_buttons.get(self.legal_form)
           # What can I do here to ensure that wherever self.legal_form is different I save the value or I get the value saved
```

Then my constants are as below :

```
LEGAL_CHOICES = (
    ('gbr', _('BGB-Society (GbR)')),
    ('ohg', _('Offene Handelsgesellschaft ')),
 
)

RADIO_BUTTON_SELECTIONS = {
    'gbr': (('yes', _('Yes')),),
    'ohg': (('yes', _('YES')), ('no', _('NO'))),
   
}
```

As you can see the fields , I want to be able to change the Choices depending on the `legal_form`  value, how can I do this in the `save()` method, or whats the best practice to achieve this ?

The biggest trouble am facing  is on how to assign choice in the model function

Answer (score 2):

the actual signature of the `save` function is:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    foo = self.my_model_field # you can access data
    self.my_model_field = 6  # you can modefiy your model fields like this
    kwargs['my_model_field'] = 7  # or modify whats going to be saved like this
    super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # actually does the saving part...
```

Comment: What of assign choices with `save()` , because I have choices like `(('yes', _('YES')), ('no', _('NO')))`. I want the choices to be assigned to `self.my_model_field`

Comment: Sorry, I can't quite understand what you are trying to achieve